# Insert dynamic image to PDF using FPDF from API call in Python Flask

Tags: python, flask, fpdf

I am trying to generate dynamic PDF documents based on some parameters I pass to my endpoint. Depending on that, different images (urls) will be fetched and inserted in my document.
I am using Flask and FPDF to generate the pdf with the json data response.

However, the problem comes in this line:

```
pdf.image('https://loremflickr.com/cache/resized/65535_52149869929_2f402fc2af_320_240_nofilter.jpg',150,10,50,60)
```

It cannot find the resource since I do not want to serve it from a local directory but to do everything online. I do not know if I have to convert my image to a stream? How can I do that?

```
class PostDogQR(Resource):

def get(self, usermail, dog_name ):

  client = pymongo.MongoClient('credentials')
  filter={'UserMail':usermail,'title':dog_name}

  result = client['dbname']['collection'].find(
    filter=filter
  )
  json_response = json.dumps(list(result), default=json_util.default)
  dog = json.loads(json_response)

  df = pd.DataFrame(dog).to_dict()
  title = df['title'][0]
  breed =df['Breed'][0]
  img_url = 'image_url'
  dog_img = df['DogImg'][0]
  dog_age = df['DogAge'][0]
  dog_desc = df['DogDescription'][0]

  pdf = FPDF(unit='mm')
  pdf.set_font('Arial', 'B', 12)
  pdf.add_page()
  pdf.multi_cell(120.0,4.0,f'Hello! My name is {title}.\nI am a {breed} and I am {dog_age} years old.\n\nThis is my story: {dog_desc}',border=0)
  pdf.image('https://loremflickr.com/cache/resized/65535_52149869929_2f402fc2af_320_240_nofilter.jpg',150,10,50,60)
  #pdf.output("yourfile.pdf", "F")
  response = make_response(pdf.output(dest='S').encode('latin-1'))
  response.headers.set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename= dog_name + '_' + usermail + '.pdf')
  response.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/pdf')
  return response
```

Here is the trace of the error:

```
2022-09-02T23:50:42.695437+00:00 app[web.1]: pdf.image(img_url,150,10,50,60)
2022-09-02T23:50:42.695437+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fpdf/fpdf.py", line 150, in wrapper
2022-09-02T23:50:42.695438+00:00 app[web.1]: return fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
2022-09-02T23:50:42.695438+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fpdf/fpdf.py", line 969, in image
2022-09-02T23:50:42.695438+00:00 app[web.1]: info=self._parsejpg(name)
2022-09-02T23:50:42.695438+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fpdf/fpdf.py", line 1738, in _parsejpg
2022-09-02T23:50:42.695439+00:00 app[web.1]: self.error('Missing or incorrect image file: %s. error: %s' % (filename, str(exception())))
2022-09-02T23:50:42.695439+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fpdf/fpdf.py", line 227, in error
2022-09-02T23:50:42.695439+00:00 app[web.1]: raise RuntimeError('FPDF error: '+msg)
2022-09-02T23:50:42.695447+00:00 app[web.1]: RuntimeError: FPDF error: Missing or incorrect image file: image url. error: [Errno 
2] No such file or directory: 'image url'
```

Comment: The `image` method takes a file path or a URL, see [docs here](https://pyfpdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/image/index.html). Have you tried putting a real image URL instead of the string `'image_url'`?

Comment: I put "image_url" just for a representation. I am including a real url right there

Comment: Show the error with the real URL then.